# Concatenate all opus audio in folder and create chapters

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, opus

I need to join multiple (mp3 or opus) audio in a directory into a single file. I also need to preserve/create each audio as a chapter. The expected outcome is that the output contains the chapter information in the file, so one can easily skip to the desired chapter using vlc player, etc.

I need to do this on Windows and have found a way to join the files, but it does not preserve the chapter information: `cmd type *.opus  | FFmpeg  -i pipe: -c:a copy all.opus`

Can anyone please tell me how to preserve chapters on Windows? I don't mind using a script as long as you tell me how to create and execute it, seeing that I am a total noob lol

The expected outcome is that it works like an audiobook. I have already seen that both mp3 & opus can have chapters, so I want to do this for all my audiobooks that have multiple files.